# Using Vim Latex-live-preview with minted package

Tags: minted, vim

I was wondering if anyone had succeeded to make vim-live-preview with the package minted.

When I tried to edit the pdflatex command winthin the script.vim by adding the `-escape-shell` switch, but here's the output for :

[image: Output]

(for real fullsize picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKaC2.png)

However when I use the following command (manually in a shell) it works fine:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape myfile
```

I was wondering if it didn't work because `minted` uses external stuff to work, therefore the live processing can't happen.

Is this an output generated by a badly installed `minted` or just something else?

For those interested in knowing more about the vim plugin, this is where I downloaded it: [Vim Latex-Live-Preview](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview)

edit:

Here's the .log of the failure (I've only put the interesting stuff)

```
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

...

```
l.3 \begin
          {document}
Pass the -shell-escape flag to LaTeX. Refer to the minted.sty documentation for
 more information.

runsystem(which pygmentize && touch tp2.aex)...disabled.
```

...

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this packag
e.

runsystem(pygmentize -S default -f latex > tp2.pyg)...disabled.

 (/tmp/tmpI8agTH/tp2.pyg)
\openout3 = `tp2.pyg'.

runsystem(pygmentize -l c -f latex -F tokenmerge             -P "verboptions= "
 -o tp2.out.pyg tp2.pyg)...disabled.

! LaTeX Error: File `tp2.out.pyg' not found.
```

...

```
l.9 \end{minted}^^M

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

Comment: Does minted work if you try the same command as in vim-latex-live-preview: `pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=no -output-dir=/tmp filename`? Do you get any error message in the log file (which should be in a random directory created by `mktempdir()` in the plugin ).

Comment: Yes it does. Clean output. I don't know where to get the log though (for the compile that generates crap)

Comment: You can change the value of 'tmp_dir' in vim-latex-live-preview to a fixed directory, and then look at the log file there.

Comment: I've been able to change the directory (I don't know too much about the programming language it's scripted with), but I've figured out how to get into the `out` folder. So I updated my question with the important bits of the logs.

Answer (score 5):

There are two steps to accomplish this on Gnu/Linux (Ubuntu):

1. In your `.vimrc` add the line

   `let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'`

   (for some reason changing the default in my texrc did not work, but the above does)
2. In your `texrc` file (inside `.vim/ftplugin.latex-suite`) go to the Compiler rules section. There you make sure that the following line:

   `TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $*'`

   is changed to:

   `TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode $*'`

Restart your (g)vim (so that all the settings are read again) and now the compilation should work with all minted items.

**Note:** As I post the answer I realize that I have never tested this with live preview, simply because I do not use that. I keep the pdf open in evince and that updates automatically every time I recompile.